# Hidden Mac administrator

Tags: mac, administrator

The admin name on my home Mac is hidden, I need to see the admin name so later I can change the password. I'm a regular user.

Answer (score 3):

To list all users and accounts, type the following in the Terminal.app:

```
dscl . list /Users
```

To list only the users, try the following:

```
dscl . list /Users | grep -v '_'
```